# Null pointer exception in Navigation In jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, runtime-error, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I got a null pointer exception while playing with navigation in jetpack compose. Dont know exactly why it is giving a null pointer exception. I have two screens Home and Details.
This is MainActivity.

```
package com.example.composenavigation

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.NavHostController
import androidx.navigation.compose.rememberNavController
import com.example.composenavigation.ui.theme.ComposeNavigationTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private lateinit var navController: NavHostController
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            ComposeNavigationTheme {
                navController = rememberNavController()
                SetupNavGraph(navController = navController)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is My Home and Detailed Screen respectively.

```
package com.example.composenavigation

import androidx.compose.foundation.clickable
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.compose.rememberNavController


@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
    navController: NavController
) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.clickable {
                navController.navigate(route = Screen.Detail.route)
            },
            text = "Home",
            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
            fontSize = MaterialTheme.typography.displayMedium.fontSize
        )
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun HomeScreenPreview() {
    HomeScreen(navController = rememberNavController())
}
```

```
package com.example.composenavigation

import androidx.compose.foundation.clickable
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.compose.rememberNavController

@Composable
fun DetailedScreen(
    navController: NavController
) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.clickable {
                navController.popBackStack()
            },
            text = "Details",
            color = Color.Red,
            fontSize = MaterialTheme.typography.displayMedium.fontSize
        )
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun DetailedScreenPreview() {
    DetailedScreen(navController = rememberNavController())
}
```

This is my Screen.kt sealed class.

```
package com.example.composenavigation

sealed class Screen(val route: String) {
    object Home : Screen(route = "home_route")
    object Detail : Screen(route = "detail_route")
}
```

This is my Nav Graph.

```
package com.example.composenavigation

import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.NavHostController
import androidx.navigation.compose.NavHost
import androidx.navigation.compose.composable
import androidx.navigation.compose.rememberNavController

@Composable
fun SetupNavGraph(
    navController: NavHostController
) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = Screen.Home.route
    ) {
        composable(
            route = Screen.Home.route
        ) {
            HomeScreen(navController = rememberNavController())
        }
        composable(
            route = Screen.Detail.route
        ) {
            DetailedScreen(navController = rememberNavController())
        }
    }
}
```

This is my stack trace.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                    Process: com.example.composenavigation, PID: 14947
                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1612)
                                                        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1938)
                                                        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate$default(NavController.kt:1933)
                                                        at com.example.composenavigation.HomeScreenKt$HomeScreen$1$1.invoke(HomeScreen.kt:26)
                                                        at com.example.composenavigation.HomeScreenKt$HomeScreen$1$1.invoke(HomeScreen.kt:25)
                                                        at androidx.compose.foundation.ClickableKt$clickable$4$gesture$1$1$2.invoke-k-4lQ0M(Clickable.kt:167)
                                                        at androidx.compose.foundation.ClickableKt$clickable$4$gesture$1$1$2.invoke(Clickable.kt:156)
                                                        at androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.TapGestureDetectorKt$detectTapAndPress$2$1$1.invokeSuspend(TapGestureDetector.kt:234)
                                                        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
                                                        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.resume(DispatchedTask.kt:178)
                                                        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.dispatch(DispatchedTask.kt:166)
                                                        at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.dispatchResume(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:397)
                                                        at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeImpl(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:431)
                                                        at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeImpl$default(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:420)
                                                        at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeWith(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:328)
                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.SuspendingPointerInputFilter$PointerEventHandlerCoroutine.offerPointerEvent(SuspendingPointerInputFilter.kt:566)
                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.SuspendingPointerInputFilter.dispatchPointerEvent(SuspendingPointerInputFilter.kt:456)
                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.SuspendingPointerInputFilter.onPointerEvent-H0pRuoY(SuspendingPointerInputFilter.kt:469)
                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.BackwardsCompatNode.onPointerEvent-H0pRuoY(BackwardsCompatNode.kt:394)
                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.Node.dispatchMainEventPass(HitPathTracker.kt:314)
                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.Node.dispatchMainEventPass(HitPathTracker.kt:301)
                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.NodeParent.dispatchMainEventPass(HitPathTracker.kt:183)
                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.HitPathTracker.dispatchChanges(HitPathTracker.kt:102)
                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.PointerInputEventProcessor.process-BIzXfog(PointerInputEventProcessor.kt:98)
                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.sendMotionEvent-8iAsVTc(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1329)
                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.handleMotionEvent-8iAsVTc(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1275)
                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.dispatchTouchEvent(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1214)
                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3138)
                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2797)
                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3138)
                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2797)
                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3138)
                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2797)
                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3138)
                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2797)
                                                        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:469)
                                                        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1859)
                                                        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3996)
                                                        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:427)
                                                        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:13737)
                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5691)
                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5485)
                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4984)
2023-02-17 14:41:48.799 AndroidRuntime           E      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5037)
                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5003)
                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5143)
                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5011)
                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5200)
                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4984)
                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5037)
                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5003)
                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5011)
                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4984)
                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7810)
                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7779)
                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7729)
                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7949)
                                                        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:188)
                                                        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
                                                        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:336)
                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:215)
                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7593)
                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:980)
                                                        Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [androidx.compose.ui.platform.MotionDurationScaleImpl@e98cd80, androidx.compose.runtime.BroadcastFrameClock@6acafb9, StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@7275ffe, AndroidUiDispatcher@777735f]
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: could you add stack trace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have too many navControllers.

You only need one:

```
setContent {
            ComposeNavigationTheme {
                navController = rememberNavController() // Leave this one
                SetupNavGraph(navController = navController)
            }
        }
```

Use an existing controller, don't create new ones:

```
@Composable
fun SetupNavGraph(
    navController: NavHostController
) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = Screen.Home.route
    ) {
        composable(
            route = Screen.Home.route
        ) {
            HomeScreen(navController = navController) // Here
        }
        composable(
            route = Screen.Detail.route
        ) {
            DetailedScreen(navController = navController) //And here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand, Can you please apply the changes rather than telling via comments please?

Comment: Changes already applied, `HomeScreen(navController = rememberNavController())` replaced with `HomeScreen(navController = navController)` and same for `DetailedScreen`.

Comment: nice this works